# Is it possible to instantiate a SQL connection via a `SqlDataConnection` that is defined in a referenced assembly?

Tags: sql-server, f#

I have a project that contains MSSQL database queries that are defined via `SqlDataConnection`.  I would like to import those queries into another (several) project(s) along with the `DatabaseContext` type that is defined for the connection object.

However, when I try to instantiate a database connection in the second project with `let databaseContext = ImportedSchema.GetDataContext()` I'm told that the `GetDataContext` method cannot be found.

Furthermore, I cannot recreate the `SqlDataConnection` types in the calling module because I will then get a type mismatch when passing the new `DatabaseContext` object to the previously defined queries.

The projects in question are referenced and compiled; my only issue seems to be with how the type-providers resolve the connection methods.

Comment: are you referencing the type provider in calling project as well? is the C# or F#? Also try taking a look at other TPs, like Sqlprovider or SQlCLient.

Comment: Are the dbs same? Could you abstract your db logic into one project and in other projects just call routines from the 1st project?

Comment: @s952163 yes; F#; the next time I start a project I'll go with Sqlprovider.

Comment: @AlexanderM; that's precisely what I'm attempting to do, however I need to instantiate a connection at the call site in order to keep queries composable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found that there was a bug that was preventing the first project from compiling and linking the `dll` correctly.  I can now see and call the respective functions.

:-/